# Crystal Reports get field headers to show only once

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report with 4 groups. I am trying to display group one information, group two information, group 3 information only once per patron (patron is the top group). The issue I'm running into is one of the fields can have multiple answers, so if I put those fields in the group header section it only displays the first response. It displays all the responses in the details section but I get a lot of redundancy. I have tried some suppress if previous field = field that didn't seem to quite do the job. Here is what I would like to see for each group:

```
Group 1 header
Field 1           Field 2           Field 3
Field 1 content   Field 2 content   Field 3 response 1
                                    Field 3 response 2
                                    Field 3 response 3

Group 2 header
Field 1           Field 2           Field 3
Field 1 content   Field 2 content   Field 3 response 1
                                    Field 3 response 2

Group 3 header
Field 1           Field 2           Field 3
Field 1 content   Field 2 content   Field 3 response 1
                                    Field 3 response 2
                                    Field 3 response 3
                                    Field 3 response 4
```

Comment: Put only field header in group header, field values in detail

Comment: I tried that as well, since there's 3 groups under patron it isn't apparent which headers belong to which details if I do it that way.

Comment: May you show the schema of your datatable?

Answer (score 0):

I will suppose you have 1 table named "Table" with 4 columns: "Patron, Field1, Field2, Field3".

So, you data would be something like this:

```
Patron1, Field1Content, Field2Content, Field3Response1
Patron1, Field1Content, Field2Content, Field3Response2
Patron1, Field1Content, Field2Content, Field3Response3
Patron2, Field1Content, Field2Content, Field3Response1
Patron2, Field1Content, Field2Content, Field3Response2
Patron3, Field1Content, Field2Content, Field3Response1
Patron3, Field1Content, Field2Content, Field3Response2
Patron3, Field1Content, Field2Content, Field3Response3
Patron3, Field1Content, Field2Content, Field3Response4
```

Then, I would try the following solution:

1. Group by {Table.Patron}.
2. Put the field {Table.Patron} in this group header.
3. Group by {Table.Field1}.
4. Group by {Table.Field2}.
5. Put the fields {Table.Field1} and {Table.Field2} in this group header.
6. Use section expert to mark the option "underlay following sections" in this group header.
7. Put the field {Table.Field3} in detail section

If you need to order by "Field3", create a third group (group by Field3).

This will work if the fields "Field1" and "Field2" has only one occurrence by "Patron". If this is not the case, you will have to adjust. Let me know if you need help.

EDIT: Final detail. To put the labels of the columns headers, you will need another group header above, without the option "underlay following section".